# Need help validating my lead-acid car battery charger experiment

Tags: charger, lead-acid

**After experimenting and testing each block separately,** I want to give it a try all together, however I have a few doubts. This is a car battery charger I'm experimenting with, for acid/lead non sealed 12V batteries:

[image]

A few things: I will use old UPS backups transformers. Sometimes they are 12v, which gets 16v after rectification, but sometimes I find ones yielding 18v, so I guess I need to regulate the input to 15v, since batteries would charge about 14.6v and I'm not sure which transformer I will find. I added a power transistor so the thing can get all the current the transformer can yield since 7815 can't handle more than 1A, nevertherless it would be under 5A (because the transformer, or because the battery should charge under 4A max), so *I can use any >8A power transistor, right?* I know the power transistor needs heatsink. *Should the 7815 also need it? I think it won't.*

Then comes the auto cut off, which as I read, cuts when the voltage reaches whatever I adjust using the 10k pot, so I would adjust it to cut after 14.6v. I don't like to use a relay though,
*can I use a mosfet instead for switching?* This one gave me problems I fixed by answers I received here: a missing filter after rectification was causing the relay to oscillate when reaching the cut off voltage.

And then current limiter: **there is no way I can find here where I live anything more elegant but use a car headlight bulb**. As I tested it, it cuts current to about 2A with high beam and about 4A with low beam. I tested this with a flat dead battery, the bulb never lights at full, and doesn't get as hot as it would be in a car. In further experiment, I placed the bulb inside an aluminum pipe as for hiding its light...worked like a heatsink, left it for 24h without temp raising or blowing. As the battery gets charged, the bulb gets darker and darker.

The battery I use for these experiments is totally dead and was discarded, it gets up to 13V but won't last 10 minutes.

So my questions are:

- Do I need to heatsink 7815?
- Can I use a >8A mosfet to replace the relay?
- If the output is to be limited to max 4A, it means all the components
  (power transistor, mosfet or relay) can be rated just a pinch over
  4A?

These kind of components is all I can find here, we don't have stores, we need to use savaged parts. For example, finding a 12v zener is all a festival.

Comment: do you know the hFE (current gain) of the NPN transistor? the 7815 output will be divided by that much; the rest of the current will go through the transistor only and not the 7815.

Comment: @user253751 yes: TT2076 (hFE1 VCE=5V, IC=1A 5; hFE2 VCE=5V, IC=5A) or C5297 (hFE MIN: 20)